# Large-scale graphs algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j, bigdata

I've started to work with Neo4j. I know there is an opportunity to extend its API with new functionality. Also, I'm interested in algorithms for large-scale graphs. 
My question is: Does anyone know any sites or other resources with the latest improvements for large-scale graphs algorithms? Or maybe you can advise me the most effective solutions for some kind of operations, like: finding the shortest path algorithms, clusterization algorithms, nearest neighbour, radius/diameter computing etc.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Much of modern applied graph theory centers on applying computational linear algebra to graph theoretic algorithms.  One prominent group involved in such work is John Gilbert's at UCSB: his group put out a piece of software called Combinatorial BLAS for efficiently executing graph algorithms using methods in computational linear algebra.